# Better commenting habits for perl

Tags: perl

I was wondering if someone could point me to an article online someone posted in a comment to one of my questions.

It was an article on better commenting habits in perl. I wanted to read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For good inspiration on documentation style, try [Perl Best Practices](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596001735) - chapter 7 is all about documentation, comments and stuff.

Comment: I will have to get that. Looks like a good book.

Comment: @Solignis - just keep in mind that book as 7 years old, so some recommendations are certainly not considered "best" these days. But just thinking about rationale behind them can bring you to right track.

Comment: Ok I will keep that in mind, I ran into a similar problem with some other perl book I picked up on Amazon, the were for Perl 5.8 I think. That was no good.

Comment: @Solignis, Some of the stuff in PBP was never considered best.  Class::STD?  Um, NO.  IMO, the real value of PBP is that it has discussion of why the recommendation was made in the first place--it invites discussion and consideration of many important concepts.

Comment: @Solignis, @daotoad - as a contribution to discussion, here is the [PBP Module recommendation commentary](https://www.socialtext.net/perl5/pbp_module_recommendation_commentary) to filter suggestions in there.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about this [Perl Monks article](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=100344)?

I would go with POD, myself.

Comment: To be honest I don't know what I am looking for. All I know is it was an article by some guy about making better use of comments.

Comment: I already looked through all of my old question, seeing if it was in there and of course it was not.